Lightweight usage of python virtual environments
When using one python environment for each single project, dependencies are well managed but a lot of heavy libraries end up being copied (python of course but also dependencies like pytorch worth several GB). Is there a way to use environments while maintaining single shared versions of these libraries?

You tagged conda, which does exactly that. Libraries are downloaded and extracted into a single, shared directory and linked into environments. In case you isntall the same version of a library to multiple envs, it only occupies space once.
Note: This is the default case. There can of course be scenarios where your filesystem structure or OS do not support hard-linking.

Thanks for the tip, I have observed that my environments in .conda/envs each take up a few GB of space, is there a recommended reading on how to diagnose & optimize this storage?

Depending on your OS and which command you have used for the storage estimation, it might be that the storage is not reported correctly
